# Java: Implementing Comparable Issue

Tags: java, object, arraylist, overriding, compareto

I'm new here and was looking for some advise on my code. I'm trying to make it possible for an arrayList `ArrayList<patient> heartPatientArray = new ArrayList<patient>(); //heart patients` to be able to be sorted on a `patient's` `arrivalTime`.

Code:

```
    class patient implements Comparable
{
    int typeSickness; //1 for heart 2 for gastro 3 for bleeding
    double arrivalTime; //what time they arrived   SORT BY
    int deathTime; // what time they are set to balk or die
    int status; //0 for being cared for, 1 to n for location in line, -1 if dead
    int personalNumberInLine; //personal number in line updated everytime someone enters the line
    double timeSpentInQueue; //total time before they either died or were able to be treated
    int idOfPerson; //unique id the person gets when entering the queue
    boolean isAlive;

    public patient(int sickness, double arrival, int ID) { //sets the patients sickness, time arrived, and ID
        typeSickness=sickness;
        arrivalTime=arrival;
        idOfPerson = ID;
    }
    public int getTypeSickness() {
        return typeSickness;
    }
    public void setTypeSickness(int typeSickness) {
        this.typeSickness = typeSickness;
    }
    public double getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }
    public void setArrivalTime(double arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }
    public int getDeathTime() {
        return deathTime;
    }
    public void setDeathTime(int deathTime) {
        this.deathTime = deathTime;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public int getNumberInLine() {
        return personalNumberInLine;
    }
    public void setNumberInLine(int numberInLine) {
        this.personalNumberInLine = numberInLine;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(patient one) {
        if (this.getArrivalTime() < one.getArrivalTime()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(this.getArrivalTime() > one.getArrivalTime()){
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

`some code edited out for time's sake`

I've tried styling it after some code I found online but I'm getting an error on `compareTo(patient one)` of Remove Override Notation, and an error on `class patient implements Comparable` telling me I must make the class abstract.

After I implement the compareTo correctly, how would I go about sorting the `heartPatientArray`?

Comment: Do you know what a raw type is? (`Comparable<T>` is a generic type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implementing the *raw* form of the `Comparable` interface.  Because of this, `compareTo` takes an `Object`, which explains why you are getting an error attempting to implement the interface.

Instead, pass your class as the type parameter.

```
class patient implements Comparable<patient>
```

Then your `compareTo` method, as is, will implement `Comparable<patient>` properly.

Typically, Java naming conventions would say to capitalize your class name.

```
class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>
```

You can sort your list with:

```
Collections.sort(heartPatientArray);
```

If you'd like to sort it in reverse order, you can specify that with:

```
Collections.sort(heartPatientArray, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

In general, you can sort it however you want by passing an instance of `Comparator<Patient>`, implementing `Comparator`'s `compare` method, taking care to pass a type parameter to `Comparable` like we are now doing for `Comparable`.  Then pass an instance of `Comparator<Patient>` as the second argument to `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Ohhh I see now, do I need the `@Override`? it's still giving me an error on that

Comment: You don't need the `@Override`, but it's recommended specifically for this reason - it will catch attempts to override/implement a method without actually overriding/implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
class patient implements Comparable
```

with

```
class patient implements Comparable<patient>
```

otherwise you need to implement `compareTo(Object o)` in your class.

When you have instances of a `Comparable` class, you can just add them to an `ArrayList` and use the method `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Even starting class names with a capital letter wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now!! Do i stil need the `@Override`? It's still giving me an error on that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what you want is to be able to compare between 2 `patient` objects. The way it is now, you are being able to compare between a `patient` and some other object. To ensure, that you are only comparing `patient` objects, you would need to change

```
class patient implements Comparable
```

to

```
class patient implements Comparable<patient>
```

The way you have down already is not wrong in any way (except for the `compareTo` param). You can, of course, compare a `patient` to some other object. If you wish to pursue that way,

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    // you would want to see if the `Object` is of `patient` type
    if( !(obj instanceof patient) )
        return -1;    // `obj` IS NOT OF TYPE `patient`; PICK YOUR RETURN VALUE; IDEALLY THROW AN EXCEPTION
    patient one = (patient) o;
    if (this.getArrivalTime() < one.getArrivalTime()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(this.getArrivalTime() > one.getArrivalTime()){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then, you can sort it by calling `Collections.sort(..)` or something.